# Angular CLI, localhost:3000 not working-"Connection Refused" (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to run my current Angular 2 project using ng serve but the browser shows the error "Connection Refused", I have tried other ports too and the problem still exists.[@angular/cli cmd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf4X6.jpg)

There seems no problem with the Angular CLI

[Connection Refused Browser error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVgQc.jpg)

Comment: Could you include the code for creating the app and listening on port 3000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://localhost:4200/ - you are maybe using wrong port number.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#usage

Answer (score 1):

First verify your machine IP Address.

On Windows, type ipconfig in Prompt (copy IPv4).
On Mac, type ifconfig |grep inet in Terminal (copy inet).

In my case this is 192.168.0.10.
Next, type the command **ng serve --host 192.168.0.10**
Ok, your app on air for all devices on same network.

Now only **http://192.168.0.10:4200/** will work, localhost not more.